# How to sync two same collections between two MongoDB databases?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, backend, feathersjs

I'm looking for some ways to sync some collections between two MongoDB databases. We are using a microservices architecture that why we store all user information in out all microservices and now sync process manage by using Redis but always it takes time to sync so I need a better way to sync data min time and without taking any kind of performance issues.

Comment: do you want schedule or event sysnc ؟

Comment: I need to do event sync.

Comment: you have redis as pub/sub ?

Comment: Yes, we are using Redis pub/sub But it can possible without Redis ?